# Exchange 2013 outbound routing / smart host for alias domain

Tags: exchange-2013

I am setting up an Exchange 2013 server, and everything works fine on the main domain. I now need to add an alias domain, and I can receive mail for this alias domain just fine. I am using a 3rd party smart host / sending service (Mailgun), and I need to authenticate for each sending domain. Each domain uses a unique login, that unfortunately cannot be changed in an easy way.

I am trying to set up Exchange so that email originating from domain1.com uses one outbound connector, with the appropriate credentials for domain1.com, and email originating from domain2.com uses another outbound connector with the appropriate credentials for domain2.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Exchange can't do that directly. You can of course have several different send connectors with the appropriate authentication information but there is no way of having Exchange select a send connector based on the sender address of the email.
But there are 3rd party add-ons that make this possible. Try MultiSendcon (http://www.servolutions.com/multisendcon.htm).

- Claus

Comment: That's a good answer, thanks, but I can do this in Postfix without spending any additional money. Thanks for answering though!!